# Перенос данных между формами

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть две формы, на одной отображаются данные в таблице на другой они добавляются. Надо что бы после нажатия сохранить на второй форме, внесенные данные отображались в таблице на первой форме. Можно конечно добавить на первую таблицу таймер который будет в случае изменений в таблице ее перестраивать. Но может вы подскажите более **правильное** решение.

Comment: Где отображаются данные? Если в DataGridView, то обновляйте его при добавлении новой записи

Comment: В форме, в которой вводите данные, создаете событие, кот. вызываете когда нажимается кнопка сохранить, в форме где отображаете данные подписываетесь на это событие и в методе обработчике либо через файл, БД, или через аргументы события передаете новую порцию введенных данных. Никакие таймеры не нужны.

Comment: @Bulson можете привести пример в ответе?

Comment: Да, напишу пример, ждите.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: пример работы]

Создадим класс модели данных с поддержкой `IDataErrorInfo` для работы `ErrorProvider` в форме

```
public class Person : IDataErrorInfo
{
    public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    #region Реализация IDataErrorInfo
    public string _Error;
    public string Error => _Error;
    public string this[string columnName] => CheckProperties(columnName);

    /// <summary>
    /// Проверка значений свойств на валидность
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="columnName">имя проверяемого свойства</param>
    /// <returns>строка с описанием ошибки</returns>
    private string CheckProperties(string columnName)
    {
        if (columnName.Equals(nameof(FirstName)) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName))
        {
            _Error = "Укажите имя";
            return _Error;
        }

        if (columnName.Equals(nameof(FirstName)) && FirstName?.Trim().Length < 2)
        {
            _Error = "Имя не может быть короче двух символов";
            return _Error;
        }

        if (columnName.Equals(nameof(LastName)) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(LastName))
        {
            _Error = "Укажите фамилию";
            return _Error;
        }

        if (columnName.Equals(nameof(LastName)) && LastName?.Trim().Length < 2)
        {
            _Error = "Фамилия не может быть короче двух символов";
            return _Error;
        }

        _Error = String.Empty;
        return _Error;
    }
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Валиден ли данный чел.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool IsValid()
    {
        var errorFN = this["FirstName"];
        var errorLN = this["LastName"];

        _Error = errorFN + " " + errorLN;
        return String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Error);
    }
}
```

**Форма ввода данных**, в ней мы объявляем событие `DataEntered`, с помощью которого будем оповещать главную форму о том, что данные готовы, и их можно забрать

```
public partial class FormInput : Form
{
    //редактируемая модель
    private readonly Person _person;

    //событие готовности данных для чтения FormMain
    public EventHandler DataEntered;

    public FormInput()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _person = new Person();

        _buttonSave.Click += ButtonSave_Click;
        this.Load += FormInput_Load;
    }

    private void FormInput_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //привязки свойств модели к текстбоксам
        _textBoxFirstName.DataBindings.Add("Text", _person, nameof(_person.FirstName),
            true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        _textBoxLastName.DataBindings.Add("Text", _person, nameof(_person.LastName),
            true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        //привязка ErrorProvider для отображения ошибок ввода
        _errorProvider.DataSource = _person;
    }

    private void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //проверяем введенные данные на валидность
        if (!_person.IsValid())
        {
            var message = $"Не все данные введены верно!\n{_person.Error}";
            var caption = "Предупреждение";
            MessageBox.Show(message, caption, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            return;
        }

        //данные валидные значит вызываем событие для оповещения FormMain
        DataEntered?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Получение чела для вставки в DGV
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="number">назначаемый порядковый номер</param>
    /// <returns>экземпляр Person</returns>
    public Person GetPerson(int number)
    {
        //создаем нового чела для передачи
        var result = new Person
        {
            OrderNumber = number,
            FirstName = new string(_person.FirstName.Trim().ToCharArray()),
            LastName = new string(_person.LastName.Trim().ToCharArray()),
        };

        //поля ввода очищаем
        _textBoxFirstName.Text = String.Empty;
        _textBoxLastName.Text = String.Empty;
        _textBoxFirstName.Focus();

        return result;
    }
}
```

**Главная форма**, с формой ввода работаем через событие

```
public partial class FormMain : Form
{
    //ссылка на форму ввода данных
    private FormInput _inputForm;
    //источник данных для DGV
    private readonly BindingSource _bsPeople;

    public FormMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _bsPeople = new BindingSource();

        _buttonOpenInput.Click += ButtonOpenInput_Click;
        this.Load += FormMain_Load;
    }

    private void FormMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _bsPeople.DataSource = typeof(List<Person>);
        //привязка к данным DGV
        _dataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        _dataGridView.DataSource = _bsPeople;
        //привязка свойств модели к колонкам DGV
        _columnOrderNumber.DataPropertyName = nameof(Person.OrderNumber);
        _columnLastName.DataPropertyName = nameof(Person.LastName);
        _columnFirstName.DataPropertyName = nameof(Person.FirstName);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Кнопка Добавить
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void ButtonOpenInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_inputForm != null)
            return;

        _inputForm = new FormInput();
        _inputForm.Owner = this;
        //подписываемся на событие готовности данных
        _inputForm.DataEntered += FormInput_DataEntered;
        _inputForm.FormClosed += InputForm_FormClosed;
        //отображаем форму
        _inputForm.Show();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Обработчик события готовности данных в FormInput
    /// Здесь мы извлекаем данные и вносим их в DGV
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void FormInput_DataEntered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //вычисляем порядковый номер для след.чела
        int number = _bsPeople.Count + 1;
        //добавляем в DGV нового чела
        _bsPeople.Add(_inputForm.GetPerson(number));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Обработчик события закрытия формы ввода
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void InputForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        _inputForm = null;
    }
}
```

Пример целиком [здесь](https://github.com/bulsond/SOrusExamples2/tree/master/WindowsFormsDataTransfer/WindowsFormsApp).