# Как добавить новый ряд в DataGridView c# Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Гуглил много, вроде находил какие-то решения, но понимания не добавилось.

Есть такой код, выдающий ошибку "System.ArgumentException: "Длина входного массива больше числа столбцов в этой таблице."

Программа - простая редактируемая таблица, в которую надо иметь возможность добавлять строчки под соответствующие колонки при помощи textField и кнопки. Базу данных не использую, т.к. надо сделать программу standalone, поэтому она сохраняет информацию в .csv файл и считывает ее оттуда же. Как правильно в данном случае реализовать добавление новых строк?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using CsvHelper;
using ExcelDataReader;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using DataTable = System.Data.DataTable;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;



namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form 
    {

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable budgetTable = new DataTable();


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataTable budgetTable = ds.Tables.Add("MainTable");
            budgetTable.Columns.Add("date", typeof(DateTime));
            budgetTable.Columns.Add("type", typeof(String));
            budgetTable.Columns.Add("name", typeof(String));
            budgetTable.Columns.Add("expenses", typeof(Int32));
            budgetTable.Columns.Add("income", typeof(Int32));

            DataRow row = budgetTable.NewRow();
            row["date"] = dateTime.Value;
            row["type"] = cbbxType.Text;
            row["name"] = nameField.Text;
            row["expenses"] = int.Parse(expenseField.Text);
            row["income"] = int.Parse(incomeField.Text);
            budgetTable.Rows.Add(row);
            DtgTable.DataSource = budgetTable;
        }


        //adds a row to the table
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cbbxType.Text) ||
                string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(expenseField.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("'Type','Expence','Income' fields cannot be 
       empty!");
            }
            else
            budgetTable.Rows.Add(dateTime.Value, cbbxType.Text, 
   nameField.Text, int.Parse(expenseField.Text), int.Parse(incomeField.Text));

        }
```

Comment: Недавно дал [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1077325/222542) на похожий в чем-то вопрос; нет БД, ввод данных в DGV.

Answer (score 1):

Это происходит из-за того, что строки добавляете в таблице, а не в экземпляре DataSet, который связан с DataGridView.

К тому же, если Вы захотите внести какие-то изменения в DataGridView, например добавить строку с помощью

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
```

тогда получите очередное исключение, которое выглядит так:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Строки нельзя программным способом добавить в коллекцию строк DataGridView, если элемент управления привязан к данным.
```

Вывод: необходимо взаимодействовать с источником данных - DataSet, выбрав определенную таблицу.

**Одно** из решений, которое может Вам помочь.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))
        MessageBox.Show("'Type','Expence','Income' fields cannot be empty!");
    else ds.Tables["MainTable"].Rows.Add(dateTime.Value, cbbxType.Text, nameField.Text, int.Parse(expenseField.Text), int.Parse(incomeField.Text));
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, попробую!