# Банальный вопрос для опытных......С# windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Совсем недавно начал изучать С# с помощью Книг, YouTube и форумов (опыта в программировании до этого не было), и пытаюсь написать программку, которая облегчила бы мне работу. **Вопрос банальный, но все, что я нашел по нему почему-то не работает. Мне нужно передать из Form1 (на которой 2 textboxa и 1 combobox) информацию, которую внесет пользователь на Form2**. Подскажите как это сделать, а лучше покажите. Заранее спасибо :-)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1077325/222542

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решений масса на самом деле, от сложных до простых. Ввиду того, что вы покамест не знаете всех глубин, то посоветую такой путь:

Код Form1:

```
    public void Function()
    {
//Создаем переменные куда закидываем значения из текстбоксов и всего другого, что нужно передать
         string TextBoxValue = TextBox1.Text; 
         string TextBoxValue2 = TextBox2.Text;
         string ComboBoxValue = ComboBox.SelectedValue;
// при выхове формы2 передаем ей наши переменные
         Form2 f2 = new Form2(TextBoxValue,TextBoxValue2,ComboBoxValue); 
         f2.show();
    }
```

Код Form2:

```
// Находим функцию основную, где есть строка "InitializeComponent()" и в аргумент кидаем ей три строчные переменные Value1,Value2,Value3:

  public Form2(string Value1, string Value2, string Value3)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MessageBox.Show(Value1+Value2+Value3); //Отображаем их
        }
```

P.S. могут быть мелкие ошибки, так как код проверить нет возможности, но на взгляд должно заработать без изменений.

P.S.S. я от нечего делать начал уроки пилить на ютюбчик, в одном из первых видео я передаю между формами переменные, можешь взглянуть, может поможет разобраться более явно https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCn_2YmDoZAZh5H-oDrs8S3g/

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.. Добрался до дома сел пробовать Ваш способ. Подписка и колокольчик с меня.

Comment: Ахах, спасибо. Прям посмеялся от души и по доброму. Будут вопросы, пишите в инсту или в комменты под видосами, обязательно отвечу, пока карантин времени много свободного)))) Можите еще и мой ответ отметить галочкой как правильный, если он вам подойдет))