# Помогите с событиями разобраться!

Tags: c#, события

```
public partial class FormStudents : Form
{

    AppService AppService = new AppService();
    AppServiceClient client;




    public FormStudents()
    {
        
        client = new AppServiceClient();
        _users = AppService.MakeList();
        InitializeComponent();
        dgvStudents.ReadOnly = true;
    }



    private List<ServerUser> UpdateTbl(List<ServerUser> users)
    {
        List<ServerUser> users2 = new List<ServerUser>();
        if (users.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var user in users)
            {
                users2.Add(user);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("users not found");
        }
        return users2;

    }


    private void btnSearchAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Iterate(_users);
        dgvStudents.DataSource = UpdateTbl(iteratedList);
        lblUpdate.Visible = false;
    }
    List<ServerUser> iteratedList;
    private List<ServerUser> Iterate(List<ServerUser> us)
    {
        iteratedList = new List<ServerUser>();

        iteratedList = us.OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToList<ServerUser>();

        return iteratedList;
    }


    public ServerUser[] ConvertToUsersArr()
    {
        ServerUser[] massiv = AppService.Users.ToArray<ServerUser>();
        return massiv;
    }

    private void btnSearchId_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServerUser serU = new ServerUser();
        List<ServerUser> lU = new List<ServerUser>();

        try
        {
            serU = client.GetInfoAboutUsersByNum(int.Parse(tbId.Text), ConvertToUsersArr());

            lU.Add(serU);

            dgvStudents.DataSource = lU;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("incorrectly filled fields");

        }

        ClearFields();
    }


    private void ClearFields()
    {
        tbName.Clear();
        tbSecName.Clear();
        tbNameOfFam.Clear();
        tbId.Clear();
        tbAge.Clear();
        tbCourse.Clear();
    }

    private void btnSearchName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServerUser serU = new ServerUser();
        List<ServerUser> lU = new List<ServerUser>();

        serU = client.ShowInfoAboutUsersByName(tbName.Text, ConvertToUsersArr());

        if (serU != null)
        {
            lU.Add(serU);

            dgvStudents.DataSource = lU;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("incorrectly filled fields");
        }

        ClearFields();
    }

    private void btgSearchAge_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServerUser[] lU;
        try
        {
            dgvStudents.DataSource = lU = client.GetInfoAboutUsersByAge(int.Parse(tbAge.Text), ConvertToUsersArr());

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("incorrectly filled fields");
        }
        ClearFields();
    }

    private void btnSearchCourse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServerUser serU = new ServerUser();
        ServerUser[] lU;
        try
        {
            dgvStudents.DataSource = lU = (client.GetInfoAboutUsersByCourse(int.Parse(tbCourse.Text), ConvertToUsersArr()));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("incorrectly filled fields");
        }
        ClearFields();
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServerUser serU = new ServerUser();
        ServerUser[] lU;
        try
        {
            dgvStudents.DataSource = lU = client.GetInfoAboutUsersByFaculty(comboBoxFac.SelectedItem.ToString(), ConvertToUsersArr());
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("incorrectly filled fields");
        }
        ClearFields();
    }
    private List<ServerUser> _users;

    private void FormStudents_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBoxFac.DataSource = AppService.ShowFaculties(ConvertToUsersArr());
        
    }

    private void btnGoToCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateForm dialog = new CreateForm(_users);
        if (dialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {

        }
        lblUpdate.Visible = true;
    }

    private void dgvStudents_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnEdit.Visible = true;
    }

    ServerUser user;

    private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var userId = this.dgvStudents.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex + 1;
        user = _users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == userId);
        
        //EditForm.StudentUpdated += EditMeth;
        EditForm.StudentUpdated += EditMeth;
        //EditMeth(user, _users);
        //EditForm editForm = new EditForm(user, _users);
        EditForm editForm = new EditForm(client, user, _users);
        if (editForm.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {

        }
        lblUpdate.Visible = true;
    }

У меня есть две формы, даже три, но не суть. Одна главная и две редактировать и создавать юнитов. Вот первая форма:

    public void EditMeth()
    {
        _users.Remove(user);
        //_users.Add(client.Save(user.Id - 1, tbName3.Text, tbSecName3.Text, tbNameOfFam3.Text, cmbFac.SelectedItem.ToString(), int.Parse(tbAge3.Text), int.Parse(tbCourse3.Text)));
        MessageBox.Show($"student with name {user.Name.ToString()} edited");
    }

}
```

Вот форма для редактирования

```
public partial class EditForm : Form
{
    public delegate void WithParams(ServerUser su, List<ServerUser> users);
    ServerUser _user;
    List<ServerUser> _users;
    AppServiceClient _client;
    public static event Action StudentUpdated;


    public EditForm(AppServiceClient client, ServerUser serU, List<ServerUser> users)
    {

        _user = serU;
        _users = users;
        _client = client;
        InitializeComponent();
        
    }

    private void EditForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tbId3.Text = _user.Id.ToString();
        tbName3.Text = _user.Name;
        tbSecName3.Text = _user.SecondName;
        tbNameOfFam3.Text = _user.NameOfFamily;
        cmbFac.DataSource = _client.ShowFaculties(_client.ConvertToUsersArr(_users.ToArray()));
        cmbFac.SelectedItem = _user.Faculty;
        tbCourse3.Text = _user.Course.ToString();
        tbAge3.Text = _user.Age.ToString();
    }

    private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var delUser = _users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == _user.Id);
        //StudentUpdated.Invoke(delUser, _users);
        StudentUpdated.Invoke();
        _users.Remove(delUser);
        _users.Add(_client.Save(_user.Id - 1, tbName3.Text, tbSecName3.Text, tbNameOfFam3.Text, cmbFac.SelectedItem.ToString(), int.Parse(tbAge3.Text), int.Parse(tbCourse3.Text)));
        MessageBox.Show($"student with name {delUser.Name.ToString()} edited");
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

Вот комментарий наставника
"Ты передаешь список всех юзеров в Create и Edit форм, но им эта информация не нужна. Лучше в момент обновления/создания студента генерировать событие StudentUpdated/Created которые будет обрабатывать главная форма."

вот эта фраза "в момент обновления/создания студента генерировать событие StudentUpdated/Created которые будет обрабатывать главная форма." мне не понятна... по конкретнее может объяснит кто, где я должен создавать событие, где его вызывать и какой метод к нему привязать и в какой форме делать это?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Перенос данных между формами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1076641/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Answer (score 2):

Объясняю :) на примере двух форм

1. Первая форма основная
2. Вторая форма добавить пользователя

первая форма выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вторая форма выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

у нас есть класс студент которого мы будем добавлять во второй форме

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SurName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }


    public Student(string name,string surname,int age)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.SurName = surname;
        this.Age = age;
    }
}
```

код первой формы

```
/// <summary>
/// Форма номер 1
/// </summary>
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Список содержит список всех студентов
    /// </summary>
    private List<Student> StudentsList;
    /// <summary>
    /// Переменная воторой формы
    /// </summary>
    CreateForm createFrom;
    /// <summary>
    /// конструктор первой формы 
    /// </summary>
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //инизиализируем список студентов
        StudentsList = new List<Student>();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    //кнопка номер 1 октрываёт форму (CreateForm) где мы добавляем пользователя
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //инициализируем форму 2
        createFrom = new CreateForm();
        //подписываемся на событие добавление нового студента во второй форме
        createFrom.OnStudentCreated += AddNewStudent;
        //показываем диалог второй формы
        createFrom.ShowDialog();
        //отписываемся от события добавление нового студента 
        createFrom.OnStudentCreated -= AddNewStudent;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Метод добавляет нового пользователя в список
    /// </summary>
    private void AddNewStudent()
    {
        //проверка на null
        if (createFrom != null)
        {
            //проверка на null
            if (createFrom.CreatedStuden != null)
            {   //добаляем нового пользовтеля в список
                StudentsList.Add(createFrom.CreatedStuden);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

код второй формы

```
/// <summary>
/// Форма 2 создание студента
/// </summary>
public partial class CreateForm : Form
{
    //делагат 
    public delegate void StudentCreated();
    //событие создание нового студента
    public event StudentCreated OnStudentCreated;
    //класс-переменная студента
    public Student CreatedStuden;
    
    public CreateForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void CreateForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
    }

    //кнопка создать нового пользователя
    private void btn_create_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //проверяем все ли поля заполнил пользователь 
        if(tx_name.Text.Length>0 && tx_surname.Text.Length>0 && tx_age.Text.Length>0)
        {   
            string name = tx_name.Text;
            string surname = tx_surname.Text;
            int age = 0;
            //проверям вел ли пользователь цифры 
            if (Int32.TryParse(tx_age.Text, out age))
            {

                CreatedStuden = new Student(name, surname, age);
                OnStudentCreated();
                Hide();
            }
            else//ошибка пользователь ввел в место возраста что то другое
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Age field can contain only digits", "Error message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

        }
        else//ошибка не все поля были заполнены верно
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can't create new user one of fields is empty", "Error message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

> Как это работает: когда мы в форме 1 нажимаем на кнопку button1 мы подписываемся на событие, которое сработает: если все поля будут правильно заполнены в форме 2 и пользователь нажмет кнопку Create new Student.
> В второй форме сработает событие  OnStudentCreated();
> и будут вызваны все методы которые подписаны на данное событие в нашем случаи это метод в форме 1 AddNewStudent(), когда он сработает новый студент будет добавлен в список StudentsList.
>
> как то так :)